# Override Map.get method

Tags: javascript

I wanted to see if I could override the get method on the Map object, this was unexpected. Can anyone tell me why?

```
Welcome to Node.js v12.8.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> Map.prototype.get = function() { console.log("test") }
test
test
test
test
test
test
...and on forever...
```

Comment: This shows, there is something in the basecode of Node, that executes `Map.prototype.get` and that's exactly why you shouldn'T override it, because it can break Node internals.

Comment: `Map` is probably used a lot even in Node.js internals, being a very generic and useful Javascript type. I'm guessing something in the CLI interface is trying to use a map (perhaps in a loop?), but thanks to your change it breaks.

Comment: Glorious !!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log` probably calls `Map` therefore creating an infinite loop.